# Why is this code rendering a background image on all of my pages, instead of just my index action?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

I am trying to make only my index action render a stylesheet/background image, but for some reason the background image is appearing on all the other pages as well.  My welcome controller is handling all of this.  The layout file is called background.css.scss.  Here is my welcome controller:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
layout :resolve_layout

def index
end

def show
end

def about
end

def testimonials
end

private

def resolve_layout
case action_name
when "index"
  "background.css.scss"

else
  "application"
end
end

end
```

Here is background.css.scss stylesheet:

```
body {
width: 100%;

background: {
  image: asset-url("sampleimage.png");
  repeat: no-repeat;
  size: 100% auto;
 }
}
```

index view:

```
background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'sampleimage.jpg' %>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `:yield` in your application.html.erb layout:

**In application.html.erb:**

```
..
<head>
  <%= yield :head %>
</head>
...
```

**Now add `content_for` block in `index` view:**

```
<% content_for(:head) do %>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'background' %>
<% end %>
```

**Keep in mind that you should NOT have `*= require_tree .`** in your `application.css` otherwise `background.css.scss` will got included in every view.

Comment: What does it mean when I get this error message,in my terminal, when restarting the server? : syntax error, unexpected tXSTRING_BEG, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)  ??

Comment: @dobsoft there must be some syntax error in one of the file. I can understand that you can't post whole error backtrace in comment. So, as you original question seems resolved, You can add another question regarding it with backtrace. You can include me to it, if you wish. I'll try to help you

Comment: Here is a link to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25615307/getting-an-error-after-rails-s-after-adding-code-to-precompile-image-asset