# Getting an error after rails s, after adding code to precompile image asset?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I just fixed an image asset compiling problem at this question-->[Why is this code rendering a background image on all of my pages, instead of just my index action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25610574/why-is-this-code-rendering-a-background-image-on-all-of-my-pages-instead-of-jus)

Now I am getting the below error message when starting up my rails server??

```
config/initializers/assets.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected tXSTRING_BEG, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
```

I can't find a fix anywhere on the internet.  Thanks.  initializers/assets.rb  :

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'

Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( background.css )` to ` config/initializers/assets.rb
```

Comment: what code is on that line? Or better yet, just add the entire file to the question.

Comment: You have `to  config/initializers/assets.rb` in the file. You it's markup problem.

Comment: Sorry maybe I'm just dense, but can you rephrase that?

Comment: I think you made a typo, can you please clarify?

Comment: They're talking about the end bit of that initializer `\`to \` config/initializers/assets.rb`

Comment: The end of your `precompile` line is odd. A legit syntax error. What are you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 1):

**There really is a syntax error.**

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( background.css )` to ` config/initializers/assets.rb
```

`%w()` is a way to specify an array of strings as words. Any element, delimited by `()`s and spaces is considered a separate array element.

`` `to` `` is what Ruby calls a `XSTRING` in your error message, it's an **executable string**: it is run as a command `to` in your operating system and its output is returned back as a string. Not in this case though. Ruby doesn't expect it being written right after an array and it's unclear what to do with it. And it's exactly what the error message says. With the code unclear, Ruby halts.

And the last thing: strings in most cases should be wrapped in `"` or `'`. These are different, however. Double quotes allow for **string interpolation** (constructs such as `"thi#{5.0.to_i}"`) while single quotes don't.

Comment: Well I'm just trying to use a template/background image for one view..should I change %w to something else and change ' to ' to " to " ??

Comment: @dobsoft AFAIK, this configuration entry expects an array. So `` ` to ` `` and everything after it shouldn't be there at all. Just `%w( ... )`